# Access to a child form

Tags: vb.net

```
  Private Sub tsGradovi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsGradovi.Click
        For Each f As Form In Application.OpenForms
            If TypeOf f Is frmGradovi Then
                f.Activate()
                Return
            End If
        Next
        Dim f2 As New frmGradovi
        f2.MdiParent = Me
        f2.Show()
        f2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        resetdgvGradova()
    End Sub
```

On this way i add the Child form to my main Form.
On that frmGradovi form i have the datagridview. Now i added class to my project.

How can i add the datagridview source from my class.

this code is not helping

```
 frmGradovi.DGV.DataSource = SQLDataset.Tables(0)
```

Probabbly because frmGradovi is mdi child of form1.

Edit:
[image]

At class konekcija i need to set the datasource for the frmGradovi form. But that frmGradovi form is an mdi child form of Form1

Comment: I dont see you setting it anywhere...? You need to use your object for example: f2 Or f in your above code..

Comment: I'm setting it on my class. Konekcija. Take a look on this picture. At class konekcija i need to set the datasource for the frmGradovi form. But that frmGradovi form is an mdi child form of Form1 http://pokit.org/get/?6bac48f91f917869c2cef890e1bd02cc.jpg

Comment: when you create the form it is `f2` - an instance.  the later isolated snippet is using the default instance `frmGradovi`.  they are 2 different things.

Comment: @Plutonix Are you trying to say that i can't access to an mdi child form from "Class" Konekcija ?

Comment: No, I am saying that in the first code block the form you create and show is `f2` (an *instance of* `frmGradovi`).  Your class just needs to use *that* reference, not `frmGradovi` which is Type/class name and can result in another new instance being created.

Comment: But how can i use that instance of `f2`, because its declared in buttonclick event and its local.. I'm trying to understand all this

Comment: First, it would help us if you translated things like *Gradovi* and *konekcija* to English so we could infer some relationships.  For the form, the class could fetch the reference from the OpenForms collection as your code already shows, or depending on how these things are related, the button click could tell *konekcija* to create the form so it would have a form reference.  Or you could pass the reference to *konekcija* or make it a property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75722/discussion-between-anel-hodzic-and-plutonix).

Comment: I really don't know how to explain it to other peoples. Here it how it looks like 
Main form with button to create MDI CHILD
http://pokit.org/get/?048258b831f46434dea6ab5bd008d3fd.jpg

On button Click i got this
http://pokit.org/get/?f27a34a282fcbe894dcdab294452e0bf.jpg

Now in my class i need to set the source for that Datagridview
http://pokit.org/get/?d9de6711d30b4b628bab7c317d220250.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid these types of conundrums is not to write Form-centric code.  They are basically a sandbox for collection user input.  The other element is to explicitly instance forms: In your code `f2` is an instance of `frmGradovi`.  Trying to reference it as `frmGradovi` elsewhere risks creating a new default instance of it (you'd later have 2 forms of Type `frmGradovi` in your Forms collection).

I dont know what a *Gradovi* or a *konekcija* is, so I will use a `Customer` example.   My app might have a `frmCustomer` and a `Customer` class.  When it comes time to display a certain customer, rather than the MDI parent form code or button click creating the form, I'd leave that job to the `Customer` class:

```
Public Class Customer
    ' myFrm is an instance of frmCustomer, which is a Type
    Private myFrm As frmCustomer
    Private myDT As DataTable

    Public Sub Display(Id As Int32)

        CustId = Id

        If myFrm Is Nothing Then
            myFrm = New frmCustomer
            ' MDI boilerplate code
            '...
            ' one time setup code like populate static CBOs:
            '...
        End If

        UpdateDisplay()
        myFrm.BringToFront()
    End Sub

    Public Sub UpdateDisplay()
        ' display code when something changes such as show new selected Customer
        ' e.g.:
        LoadCustDataToDataTable(CustId)

        With myFrm
            .tbfirstName.Text = FirstName
            .tbLastName.Text = LastName
            ' ...etc
            .dgvPastOrders.DataSource = myDT
        End With
    End Sub
```

The "key" is that the Customer class is in charge of the customer form.  It creates it and retains a reference to it.  When the user clicks `Save` that task too would be offloaded to the `Customer.Save` method.

You'll have other gyrations to add to handle when the user closes that form (if they are allowed to close versus just hiding it).  In your current approach, your class could fish the reference to its form from the collection as it needs it.